# How to push with P4 Sandbox

Tags: perforce

**Summary**: What is the equivalent to `git pull` and `git push` when using P4Sandbox?

**Details**:

I'm more familiar with git so I'm trying out using P4Sandbox with Perforce.  I've been able to commit my changes in my local sandbox, but I am having trouble pushing them to the central server.  I'd prefer to use P4V, but knowing the command line option to complete this task would be great as well.

Answer (score 1):

Submitting changes to the "mirror" stream will cause P4Sandbox to submit to the shared server. Similarly shelving a change to the "mirror" stream will cause P4Sandbox to shelve to the shared server.

In the stream graph of P4V you should will see a stream at the top of the graph with a badge that looks is using echolocation. Right click that and select "Copy to ''". In the resulting dialog select the child stream that has the contents you want to push, enter a changelist description, and press 'Copy'.

From the command line, you can run 'p4 copyup' from the development stream you want to push. This will copy your changes up and switch your workspace. A 'p4 submit' at this point will send the changes to the shared server.